# Full Sycl support in Eigen

Tags: eigen

Although there is some [SyCl](https://www.khronos.org/sycl) support in [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), it seems to be restricted to the Tensor module.

Sycl does have `sycl::vec<T,int>` types, are there any plans on using that as a `packet<>` in the arch backends ?

Would that be sensible at all, or am I missing something?

Comment: It may be better to create a feature request or discuss it on the IRC channel or mailing list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We at Codeplay are focusing on the Tensor module as it is used in machine learning ( the field that we are focusing on ).
As  m7913d mentioned your question should be turned into feature request and communicated with the Eigen community ( http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page#Mailing_list ).

To answer your question from our perspective: In short unfortunately the answer to your question is not yet.

In order to use the Eigen Core with SYCL, not only the Eigen Packet struct needed to be specialised but also the Eigen back-end expression tree for Eigen core is needed to be specialised for SYCL as well.
Currently we are supporting the Tensor module in Eigen because unlike the Expression tree in Eigen core, the Expression back-end for Tensor has been templated by a Device parameter. Therefore, it is straightforward to specialise it for any custom device. We are currently working on implementing the BLAS library for SYCL it is an open source project which can be found here. Once it is completed we may be able to use it as a back-end for Eigen core in order to eventually support the core back-end. However, accepting such back-end for Eigen core depends on the approval of the Eigen maintainer team.